# AWS linux test page when using https

Tags: apache, http, https

I am using aws instance, apache server and tomcat7 under apache.
I am able to hit my site with "http": http://www.example.com and everything is normal.
But when i am trying to hit the using "https" : https://www.example.com, i get Linux AMI test page. Is there any configuration i need to change in the httpd config file?

I have also tried : netstat -ptnl | grep ":443" and the response is : 
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      11722/httpd

My ELB listeners : 
[image]

So, where am i going wrong?

Comment: Which instance type are you using? Amazon Linux? Ubuntu? Which documentation did you follow for https, this one: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html ?

Answer (score -1):

From the ELB configuration you have shared it looks like you have configured ssl on the ELB.

Unless you intend to do ssl termination on the apache server, the issue should be re-solved by routing traffic from elb to instance over http.
After the reconfiguration, the config should look like

```
HTTPS 443 HTTP 80 Change <cert> ACM change
```

The ssl cert will be used for encrypting the req/response from clients to the ELB. From ELB to instance, the communication will be over http.